# Connected and disconnected dimensions

Tags: spacetime, differential-geometry, topology, spacetime-dimensions

The usual way of determining the dimensionality of space is from the number of values needed to define a unique point.

However, when choosing a ski, my body is defined by two numbers - my mass and height.  By the previous definition alone, mass and height represent a 2-dimensional space (that everyone fits on).  This is intuitively unhelpful as these 2 dimensions are “disconnected”.

An example normally given, is that a spatial plane requires two numbers (e.g. $x$ and $y$) to define a unique point, and hence is 2-dimensional.  This seems to intuitively be what one expects as 2-dimensions, perhaps because they are CONNECTED.

**I am after determining what extra fundamental axiom/rule is required to show that 2 separate dimensions (in their own right) are actually “connected”.**
Whilst possible answers might include concepts of “invariant distance”, isotropy, Euclid’s axioms etc., I am worried that these over-prescribe a particular sub-set of 2-dimensional space possibilities.  Rotational freedom appears closest to what I am looking for.

Any help pointing me to relevant literature or quick answers would be appreciated.

**Whilst I am at it, I do not even have the set of rules that define 1-dimension!**

Comment: I can see that a metric added to a grid of 2 independent dimensions makes it clearly 2-dimensional.  What about going not this far but just adding a property that points are connected by lines or arcs, which may infer some order, even if no measurement? Thus we are allowing the concept of a route to travel, which the ski example would make no sense.

Comment: Your definition of "disconnected" seems that each axis of a space has different unit. We can freely imagine such space.

Comment: A lady’s body for the purpose of fitting clothes has been described as a triple of bust, waist and hip measurements. They are all the same unit, but hardly representing or modelled by 3 dimensional space!

Answer (score 0):

The experimental way to determine dimensionality of space is to look at things like the power-law for the gravitational potential or electrical potential. The "usual" power for fall-off in radius $r$ depends on the dimensions of the space as you'd get a different power for applying Gauss's law in 1 or 2 or 4 dimensional space.

There are several experimental efforts looking for "small extra-dimensions" using this technique, by the way.  Here "small" means compact. An intuitive example would be that a human hair looks one dimensional from far away but, to a louse living on it, looks two dimensional with the long dimension being "infinite" (or close enough for the louse) and the direction around a cross-section being compact because you quickly come back to your original location if you travel that way.  Ala the argument above, there's theory that suggests there are such "small" dimensions, which would appear as deviations to the power-law that we're used to seeing when you measure appropriate forces at close enough distances.

Comment: Love the example about the bug and human hair!  Whilst I was not seeking quite the direction you have taken this, I do take the point that a scientific phenomenon can indicate a dimensional dependence, e.g. Maxwell's electromagnetic equations and the Lorentz transformation.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of defining the dimension of a space purely topologically. These include the Lebesgue covering dimension and the inductive dimension. They are very general and do not depend in any way on assumptions such as the existence of a [Riemannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) or [semi-Riemannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) metric, or the notion of things like rotations. By these definitions, your skiing example is a 2-dimensional space.

To use these definitions, essentially all you need is that there is some sensible way of defining continuity.  If you want to express this in terms of "needing $n$ numbers" to define a point, then you can do that, but you also need to require that the mapping is continuous. Otherwise it won't work, because, e.g., there are (wildly discontinuous) one-to-one mappings between the line and the plane.

The word "connected" is probably not the best choice, because in topology it has a specific technical meaning, which is different from what you have in mind. Maybe "related" would work better.

To capture your notion that a space has $n$ related dimensions, we need to add some structure beyond what is present in a bare [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold). One way to do this would be to require that there be some metric structure present, which could be either Riemannian or semi-Riemannian. If we have such a structure, then I would say that the dimensions are related to one another.

Example: In your skiing example, we could define a metric, but it would probably be silly and not of any real-world interest.

Example: In special relativity, there is a semi-Riemannian metric that is of interest for spacetime. This connects to your intuition about rotations, because the metric is invariant under rotations.

Comment: Actually there are continuous mappings between the real line and the real plane. These are called *space filling curves*. After their discovery people were doubting if dimension really was  a topological invariant (namely, of such maps could have a continuous inverse as well) and it was only in the 30s or thereabout that, using quite advanced techniques from algebraic topology, it was proved to actually be invariant.

Comment: Agree about the use of related, perhaps "dependent" is closer.  I also suspect that a metric is the answer.  I think I have nearly convinced myself that 1-dimension space always requires a metric, otherwise one cannot for instance state it is homogeneous.  Then the connection between 2 independent dimensions that makes them "dependent" is to define a metric for each point in the "grid". This requires that the metric for each separate dimension is the same (hence time being measured in metres of light-travel).

Comment: You mention a "bare manifold", i.e. before a metric is added.  I am unsure if such a manifold adds value (if too bare), but Wiki's definition of a manifold is "In mathematics, a manifold is a topological space that locally resembles Euclidean space near each point" suggests Euclidean by definition (e.g. not Lorentzian), i.e. includes a metric.  However, putting aside confusing definitions, I take your point but wonder if there is such as thing as structure that adds something but without a metric?